# the plt.show() not working with this code

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
 
data = pd.read_csv("training5.csv")
X= np.array(data[['x1','x2']])
y=np.array(data['y'])
np.random.seed(55)
 
estimator = LogisticRegression()
 
 
 
def randomize(X, Y):
    permutation = np.random.permutation(Y.shape[0])
    X2 = X[permutation,:]
    Y2 = Y[permutation]
    return X2, Y2
 
X2, y2 = randomize(X, y)
 
def draw_learning_curves(X, y, estimator, num_trainings):
    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
        estimator, X2, y2, cv=None, n_jobs=1, train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, num_trainings))
 
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
 
    plt.grid()
 
    plt.title("Learning Curves")
    plt.xlabel("Training examples")
    plt.ylabel("Score")
 
    plt.plot(train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
             label="Training score")
    plt.plot(test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="y",
             label="Cross-validation score")
 
 
    plt.legend(loc="best")
 
    plt.show()
```

the data http://www.mediafire.com/file/mik8ufsxp91auy4/training5.csv/file
im also new to ML and python so could someone please explain from def randomize(X,Y) till the end of the code how every detail works
TIA <3

Comment: SO isn't a place where people do your homework.

Comment: You did not call draw_learning_curves with arguments in the code shown.

Answer (score 0):

That's a big ask, and unfortunately no, it isn't feasible to walk the dog through every line of this code in a Stackoverflow answer. I recommend you check out [DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com) for excellent courses that cover everything you're showing here.

The simple immediate solution is for you to call your function after you define it. At the end of your current block of code simply add:

```py
draw_learning_curves(X2, y2, estimator, 5)
```

This executes the function you defined with your `X2`, `y2`, and `estimator` variables as parameters. Change the last argument to whatever number of trainings you'd like to visualize.